# Which codec does Flash use to stream video from web cameras to RTMP, RTMFP servers?

Tags: flash, video, streaming, video-streaming, red5

Which codec does Flash use to stream video from web cameras to RTMP, RTMFP servers?

What I ment to say: we connect to some server like Red 5, we start streaming video onto it from our flash RIA. In what codec video is traveling from RIA to Red 5?

Comment: No codec uses Flash. Perhaps you meant which codec does Flash use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash encodes h.263 Sorenson Spark.